# How do I package a Unity lens?

Tags: application-development, ppa, packaging, launchpad, lenses

I'm new to Ubuntu apps and Launchpad. I've created a Unity lens using Quickly, but I'm stuck on how to deploy it. I have two questions.

1. I can create a .deb file using `quickly package`, but when I install it, I still need to manually restart Unity and run the project using `quickly run`. After installing this lens from the Ubuntu Software Center, will users have to do this as well? If so, how can I do this automatically so they don't have to?
2. I'm confused as to what I need to do to make my project be installed using a PPA. I've pushed my code to Launchpad using Bazaar. I've also created a PPA, PGP key and a SSH key. What do I need to do next?

Any help would be appreciated.

My project in launchpad is [`unity-lens-php`](https://launchpad.net/unity-lens-php).